# Combine rows in scikit during ColumnTransformer transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As a working example modified from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#columntransformer-for-heterogeneous-data), say I have

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

X = pd.DataFrame(
    {'type': ['type1', 'type1', 'type1', 'type1', 'type2', 'type2', 'type2', 'type3', 'type3', 'type4'],
     'feat': ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','A','B','A']})

column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [('type_', OneHotEncoder(),['type']),
     ('feate_', OneHotEncoder(),['feat'])],
    remainder='drop')

column_trans.fit(X)
column_trans.get_feature_names()
column_trans.transform(X).toarray()
```

which will output

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

What I'm trying to get is instead an encoding in which all rows for a given `type` are combined. I.e. an output that looks like

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

where all `feat`s for a given `type` are switched on, but there is only one row per `feat`. Is `ColumnTransformer` the right way to do that? Can I do it with only `OneHotEncoder`?

I don't care about the identity matrix on the left. Really what I'm after is just

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I've tried playing around with `ColumnTransformer` or using just `OneHotEncoder` with something like

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories=X['feat'].unique())
for t in X['type'].unique():
    print(t)
    print(ohe.fit_transform(X[X['type'] == t]).toarray())
```

with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already working in `pandas` you can use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 'type' and aggregate with [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) for multi label encoding.

```
pd.get_dummies(X, columns=['feat']).groupby('type', as_index=False).max()
```

Output

```
    type  feat_A  feat_B  feat_C  feat_D
0  type1       1       1       1       1
1  type2       1       1       1       0
2  type3       1       1       0       0
3  type4       1       0       0       0
```

---

With `sklearn` you can use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html). But you have to prepare your data with pandas anyway and gather the labels in a `list`. In my version of `sklearn` `MultiLabelBinarizer` does not work with `ColumnTransformer` because of a mismatch in the signature of the `transform` methods.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(X.groupby('type')['feat'].apply(list))
```

Output

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

Alternatively, you can first use `OneHotEncoder` and then group and aggregate in `pandas`.

```
column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [('feate_', OneHotEncoder(),['feat'])],
    remainder='passthrough')

pd.DataFrame(column_trans.fit_transform(X)).groupby(4).max().set_axis([list('ABCD')], 1)
```

Output

```
         A    B    C    D
4                        
type1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
type2  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
type3  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
type4  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```